# Error:Could not determine the dependencies of task

Tags: android, api, sdk, build.gradle, android-studio-2.2

> Error:Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
>   In order to use Instant Run with this device running API 17, you must install platform 17 in your SDK

This appears while running?

[image: This appears while running?]

when I click out like this!

[image: this]

Comment: Try to open SDK Manager and install Android Versions you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you should consider unplugging the connected device/emulator and after that uninstall the app from the device and then connect and re run for more discussion about this 
[Instant run issue on Android Studio 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619280/instant-run-issue-on-android-studio-2-2)
But during the improvements and bug fixes of Android Studio 2 beta now android studio to use instant run you have to install the corresponding sdk as found in your device. So to install in Android studio click sdk manager...then sdk platform check the sdk wanted the wait while its downloading after that you are good to go!!
About bug fixes and improvements in android studio 2 beta versions and instant run improvement visit here!http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio22beta3