# Instant run issue on Android Studio 2.2

Tags: android, android-studio

I have updated my android studio to 2.2, Since then I get this strange issue when running the studio gives me error  Instant Run requires that the platform corresponding to your target device (Android 1.0) is installed. I am using Note 4 on android 6.0.1. Why is this error happening ?

[image: Instant run issue]

Comment: I had this too. Just unplug it, click to run again, plug it and select your device.

Comment: Today I had same issue and I proceed with install and continue and everything worked fine.

Comment: I have tried it several times , What does it want to install anyway ? what exactly is android 1.0 ?

Comment: @RenanBandeira Thanks for the tip. My S6 asked me if I wanted to continue with USB debugging. As soon as I accepted this dialog, my Samsung appeared with the correct Samsung name in the list of devices (instead of an obscure ~10 digit number). My app run. Second attempt I had to select Install and Continue but it asked for the correct version of Android (platform 22) in my case.

Comment: But can i just turn off the alert/pop-up? And not ALL of instant run? I don’t want that specific Android SDK, have all these older SDKs take up so much space...

Answer (score 21):

If you have connected your android device, unplug it then uninstall the current app. Then plug the usb back and click run. You good to go.

Comment: I am not sure if i have to uninstall the app, but just unplug and then plug it back again made the trick

Comment: You don't have to uninstall the app but only if it persists.

Comment: I have not even been able to install my app for first time :(

Comment: Then just unplug the USB from the computer and plug it back in again then run app.

Answer (score 3):

Am also facing similar issues since i downloaded the upgrade patch for android studio 2.2 
i have noticed it happens when Android monitor says device offline [Android device says offline yet connectet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYw5c.png)

The reason why the device goes offline and yet its connected properly i don't know yet.  When i click download i get this error [Package id platforms;android-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkEd0.png)
I currently sole this temporarily by checking if android monitor says device offline, if yes i unplug the USB and plug it back in else it just runs fine

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problems as you all and I solved it.

If you get an error like 'error **Package id platforms;android-1** ' you must go to: Tools -> Android->SDK Manager, and thed to SDK Platforms. Make sure that 'Show Package Details' tab is checked (so that you can see all packages) and Android 1.1 package installed. 
[image]

Otherwise just install it like all others packages. After you do this, restart Android Studio, unplug/plug phone. You will be asked then to conform something at your device, say ok and you fixet problem.

Comment: Best answer. Thanks!

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, but with an emulator.
So the answer of unplug/plug the device is not applicable to me.

I deleted my emulator and create a new one in Android Studio.
And, it's solved...

Answer (score 1):

Connect to your computer as MTP. After this Android Studio will recognize your device and SKD could install for it.l

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this by changing the USB cable. The one given by Samsung is useless.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it solved after I approve the confirmation box for connecting the phone to the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Running the android studio as sudo did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

i got same problem , i have unplug my Device  then uninstall the current app. Then plug the usb back and click run. i am good to go and my Problem

Answer (score 0):

In this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iW_JmBj72_k) there is a Solution for Error running app: Instant Run requires 'Tools | Enable ADB integration' to be enabled. It worked for me to disable the instance run error messages.

Answer (score 0):

In my case SDK location was incorrect.

I disabled Instant_Run option.

please check SDK version in local.properties file.