# Instant Run requires that the platform corresponding to your target device (Android 7.0 (Nougat)) is installed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have installed Android 2.3.3 in my ubuntu 16.04. while i am running the app it show the following Dialog Box. which option should i choose and what is the difference between the these two options

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYNNx.png)

Comment: dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619280/instant-run-issue-on-android-studio-2-2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instant run issue on Android Studio 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619280/instant-run-issue-on-android-studio-2-2)