# Android studio 3.1 instant run for android 8.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-run

I keep getting the `Instant Run requires that the platform corresponding to your target device (Android 8.1 (Oreo)) is installed`. No matter what I press, the same dialog shows on the next run.

Running the beta version of android studio 3.1 beta4

The feature works great on older versions of android (like 8.0)

Comment: Did you try disabling the `Instant Run` option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instant run issue on Android Studio 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619280/instant-run-issue-on-android-studio-2-2)

Comment: @ReazMurshed this is for a older version on android studio.

Comment: I don't want to disable instant run, the feature works great for other older android versions.